# Highlighting a row that meets multiple requirements in other columns

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

Just came across this forum while trying really hard to solve a problem.  What I need to do is highlight specific rows in this sheet.  The ones I want to be highlighted are the ones that fit multiple criteria...

1. I want to find all duplicates in Column G.  Then...
2. Of those duplicates, I want to keep (or highlight) the one that has the smaller number in column A.

[image]

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the conditional formatting with "countif" as [explained here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/google-sheets-highlight-duplicates/#color-rows) and also sort on both columns G & A (using multiple column sort) should get you the expected result